# Gibbs lectures in print?

Tags: reference-request

Do you know if text versions of the Gibbs lectures exist somewhere? I am especially curious about ["Integrable systems: a modern view"](http://jointmathematicsmeetings.org/meetings/national/jmm/deift) (e.g., because Kontsevich's mention of such systems).

Comment: Could this question be restricted or split to ask *either* for the Deift-talk or an equaivalent *or* for published Gibbs lectures.
The mixing of two somewhat unrelated issues seems a bit problematic to me (if only for 'systematic' reasons).
 

Answer (score 2):

many of the older lectures have been published by the AMS; my favorite, by Dyson on the relationship of math and physics, is here:

http://www.math.uh.edu/~tomforde/Articles/Missed-Opportunities-Dyson.pdf

most of the recent ones (including the one by Deift) have not, regrettably:

http://www.ams.org/meetings/lectures/meet-gibbs-lect

Answer (score 2):

Deift has many published works on essentially the subject of his talk (which appears to be his standard colloquium talk), but none with that precise title.

Answer (score 1):

The question is old but I have just now found something of interest.

Dear Thomas have you seen to [this talk](http://icb.u-bourgogne.fr/Matveev2009/slides/Deift.pdf) by Deift, having the same precise title?

It was given at the Conference in honor of Vladimir B. Matveev's 65th birthday hold in July 2009, while the Gibbs'lecture were given in January of the same year, so probably they are the same talk.